# Make the button do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a random quote generator and I've linked the GET request with the button. I'm kinda clueless with API's this is my first try and I'd like for someone to point out my mistake. Here is my code:

```js
$("#randomQuote").on('click', function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&callback=", function(data) {
    $(".messageQuote").html(data[0].content + " - " + data[0].title)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="text-center">random quotes</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well col-xs align-self-center messageQuote text-center">
    <button id="randomQuote" type="button">random quote</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/grodis/pen/ZXNZvz?editors=1011

Comment: CodePen is `https`, your quote JSON site thing is `http`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Like @Xufox said: you need the `HTTPS` link: `https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=` that works for me

Comment: When changing the link. it worked fine for me

Comment: using https link helped, but I still get `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` when running the code in the snippet. It works when pasting the request in the dev console. I  do not know why that is though

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!